# Array of elements to control view (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-directive

### **What I'm trying to do:**

Is there any way to use an array of elements to populate a div with children in AngularJS?

I want to be able to have an array of custom elements, and as I update the array, it updates the view. The directives for the custom elements need to `$scope.$digest()` the elements each time I make an update.

---

### Pseudo Code:

#### html

```
<div id="parent" ng-controller="parentCtrl" ng-bind-html="arrOfElems"></div>
```

#### Javascript

```
app.controller('levelCtrl', ['$scope', '$compile', '$element', function(scp, cmpl, elem) {
  scp.arrOfElems = ['<ell></ell>', '<r-ell></r-ell>', '<sqr></sqr>'];
}]);

app.directive('ell', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: <div class="block"></div>
  };
});
app.directive('rEll', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: <div class="block"></div>
  };
});
app.directive('sqr', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div class="block"></div>'
  };
});
```

Ideally, the resulting html would be:

```
<div id="parent" ng-controller="parentCtrl" ng-bind-html="arrOfElems">
  <ell>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </ell>
  <r-ell>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </r-ell>
  <sqr>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </sqr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a simple loading directive that compiles them and inserts them

```
<div id="parent" ng-controller="parentCtrl" my-loader="arrOfElems"></div>
```

Untested but should work:

```
app.directive('myLoader',function($compile){
   return function(scope, elem, attrs){
        var arrOfElems=scope[attrs.myLoader];
        angular.forEach( arrOfElems, function(newEl){
          elem.append( $compile(newEl)(scope) );
        });
   }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/GzdsGfWxVkKFJ8qL3aon?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Tested it out, worked perfectly! Initially I thought it would only add the elements when angular bootstraps, but it updates the view as you update the array.

Comment: i didn't catch the part about updating array. Might have to add a watch and empty the element when array changes